# Extending woocommerce admin product search

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic, meta-query

I have added custom fields to products but searching in admin page does not work.
Tried many codes and found this one that finally works [here](http://dominykasgel.com/extend-search-custom-post-types-wordpress-admin/) but it removes default searching by title so search by title doesn't work anymore if using that code.

How can I edit code to adds meta key search but still works on default search?

Thank you for your help!

Here is the code:

```
function extend_admin_search( $query ) {

 // Extend search for document post type
 $post_type = 'product';
 // Custom fields to search for
 $custom_fields = array(
        "_productquality",
    );

    if( ! is_admin() )
        return;

    if ( $query->query['post_type'] != $post_type )
   return;

    $search_term = $query->query_vars['s'];

    // Set to empty, otherwise it won't find anything
    $query->query_vars['s'] = '';

    if ( $search_term != '' ) {
        $meta_query = array( 'relation' => 'OR' );

        foreach( $custom_fields as $custom_field ) {
            array_push( $meta_query, array(
                'key' => $custom_field,
                'value' => $search_term,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ));
        }

        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    };
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'extend_admin_search' );
```

Answer (score 2):

I solve this problem it's too easy just paste the code in `functions.php` and the code do not remove the default searching by title.

See The Example with screenshots

> First, add your Custom Field Group with **Post Type is equal to Product** and add a new field with field label and field name as like

[image: adding custom]

> Add some text in the custom field that shows in the product edit page

[image: editing in product page]

> In the last step just add the code in `function.php` and separate your
> field names by commas in array `$custom_fields = array("_product_test");`

```
function search_by_custom_field_for_admin( $search, &$wp_query ) {
    global $wpdb, $pagenow;
    $post_type = 'product';
    $custom_fields = array(
        "_product_test",
    );

    if ( 'edit.php' != $pagenow || !is_admin() || $wp_query->query['post_type'] != $post_type ) {
        return $search;
    }

    $get_post_ids = array();
    foreach ($custom_fields as $custom_field_name) {
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page'  => -1,
            'post_type'       => $post_type,
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => $custom_field_name,
                    'value' => $wp_query->query['s'],
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
            )
        );
        $posts = get_posts( $args );
        if(!empty($posts)){
            foreach($posts as $post){
                $get_post_ids[] = $post->ID;
            }
        }
    }
    $wp_query->set('post__in', $get_post_ids);
    return $search;
}
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'search_by_custom_field_for_admin', 999, 2 );
```

> After changes, you can see the searching results in the screenshot

[image: after changes]